# I'm using ajax to get Map<String,String> State data as stateCode and stateName from controller to show in JSP page

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsp

I'm using ajax to get Map<String,String> State data as stateCode and stateName from controller and want to show in JSP page as multiple selectbox. Like in jsp we can use ${states} to get all states and by ForEach loop show in every select box. But I have no idea that how to use ajax response as JSP object. For references code is below... Thanks in advance.
Here in my code multiple selectboxand based on selected I have to show data in next multiselect dropdown...

```
<div class="form-block">
                <div class="custom-select">
                    <span>Region</span>
                    <ul id="region" onchange="regionChange()">
                    <c:forEach items="${regionMap}" var="map">
                        <li>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" class="reg"  id="${map.key}" value="${map.value}" />${map.value}</label>
                        </li>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-block">
                <div class="custom-select">
                    <span>State</span>
                    <ul id="statesUL" onchange="stateChange()" >
                    <c:forEach items="${stateMap}" var="map">
                        <li>
                             <label><input type="checkbox" class="reg" id="${map.key}" value="${map.value}" />${map.value}</label>
                        </li>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="form-block">
                <div class="custom-select">
                    <span>City</span>
                    <ul id="city" onchange="cityChange()">
                    <c:forEach items="${cityMap}" var="map">
                        <li>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" class="reg"  id="${map.key}" value="${map.value}" />${map.value}</label>
                        </li>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>


$.ajax({
        type : "get",
        url: "http://localhost:4005/allStateHO",
        cache: false,
        data:"region="+regionCheckBox,
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            },
        
        error:function(){
            alert('Error loaded');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. Are you posting a list of state codes and names to a JSP? Where's your JSP code? In a JSP is very easy to get all your parameters and then do anything you want with them.

Comment: @Sergio I have added JSP code.

Comment: I can't see the rest of your code, but in your JQuery success function you are doing nothing, I mean, you're only writing something to the console.log while you should be getting the list of cities and assign them to some cities array

Comment: I have solve this problem by using append() fn.